# Shoutcast Server php cannot run

Tags: php

**The following is my config.php**

```
<?php
$CONFIG['music_dir'] = './music/anak-ayam.mp3';
$CONFIG['encoder_path'] = 'lame.exe';
$CONFIG['bitrate'] = '64';
$CONFIG['server_name'] = 'Test Shoutcast Server';
$CONFIG['server_genre'] = 'Random';
$CONFIG['server_url'] = 'http://localhost:45401/';
$CONFIG['server_public'] = '0';
$CONFIG['metadata_interval'] = '8192';
```

**The following is my run.php**

```
<?php // $Id$

require 'config.php';
require 'server.php';
require 'shoutcast.php';
require 'audiosource.php';
require 'http.php';

set_time_limit(0);

$Server = new Server();

$AudioSource = new AudioSource();
$AudioSource->bitrate = $CONFIG['bitrate'];
$AudioSource->encoder = $CONFIG['encoder_path'];
$AudioSource->metadata_interval = $CONFIG['metadata_interval'];
$AudioSource->populate_playlist($CONFIG['music_dir']);
$AudioSource->open_next_file();

$Shoutcast = new Shoutcast();
$Shoutcast->server = &$Server;
$Shoutcast->source = &$AudioSource;
$Shoutcast->metadata_interval = $CONFIG['metadata_interval'];
$Shoutcast->server_name = $CONFIG['server_name'];
$Shoutcast->server_genre = $CONFIG['server_genre'];
$Shoutcast->server_url = $CONFIG['server_url'];
$Shoutcast->server_public = $CONFIG['server_public'];
$Shoutcast->hook_to_server();

$HTTP = new HTTP();
$HTTP->server = &$Server;
$HTTP->shoutcast = &$Shoutcast;
$HTTP->hook_to_server();

$Server->listen();
```

I'm running on Windows 7, and when I try to run the script, this is the output that I'm getting

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\shoutcast>php run.php
Playing:
```

While the expected output is

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\shoutcast>php run.php
Playing: anak-ayam.mp3
```

I would like to create their own online radio server please help. How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you post your `run.php`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the windows .Can you change the path of the `mp3` from

```
$CONFIG['music_dir'] = './music/anak-ayam.mp3';
```

to something like

```
$CONFIG['music_dir'] = 'C:/music/anak-ayam.mp3';
```

Comment: Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1:45400

Comment: Now thats a problem . This means your server not running . Can you verify if your server is listening to port `45400` and `45401` . Do you see your HTTP server page at `http://localhost:45401`